# Use of cuDNN RNN

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, cudnn

I will first summarize what I *think* I understood about cuDNN 5.1 rnn functions:

**Tensor dimensions**

```
x = [seq_length, batch_size, vocab_size] # input
y = [seq_length, batch_size, hiddenSize] # output

dx = [seq_length, batch_size, vocab_size] # input gradient
dy = [seq_length, batch_size, hiddenSize] # output gradient

hx = [num_layer, batch_size, hiddenSize] # input hidden state
hy = [num_layer, batch_size, hiddenSize] # output hidden state
cx = [num_layer, batch_size, hiddenSize] # input cell state
cy = [num_layer, batch_size, hiddenSize] # output cell state

dhx = [num_layer, batch_size, hiddenSize] # input hidden state gradient
dhy = [num_layer, batch_size, hiddenSize] # output hidden state gradient
dcx = [num_layer, batch_size, hiddenSize] # input cell state gradient
dcy = [num_layer, batch_size, hiddenSize] # output cell state gradient

w = [param size] # parameters (weights & bias)
dw = [param size] # parameters gradients
```

**cudnnRNNForwardTraining / cudnnRNNForwardInference**

```
input: x, hx, cx, w
output: y, hy, cy
```

**cudnnRNNBackwardData**

```
input: y, dy, dhy, dcy, w, hx, cx
output: dx, dhx, dcx
```

**cudnnRNNBackwardWeights**

```
input: x, hx, y, dw
output: dw
```

---

**Questions:**

1. Is the following training workflow for multi-layer RNN (*num_layer* > 1) correct?

> 1. init hx,cx,dhy,dcy to NULL
> 2. init w: (weights:small random values, bias: 1)
> 3. forward
> 4. backward data
> 5. backward weights
> 6. update weights: w += dw
> 7. dw = 0
> 8. goto 3.

2. Do you confirm cuDNN already implements stacked rnn when *num_layer* >
   1? (no need to call *num_layer* times forward/backward methods)
3. Should I re-inject hidden state & cell state into the network at next batch?
4. The output in lstm/gru formulas is *hy*. Should I use *hy* as output or *y*?

Same question posted [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1005271/gpu-accelerated-libraries/use-of-cudnn-rnn/) (I will synchronize answers)

Comment: Note that the inner-most dimension of the input tensor usually doesn't have anything to do with the vocabulary size (unless you're using one-hot tensors or something); usually, it's the size of the embedding.